Japanese film with people on an island?
I am trying to remember the name of a film that was probably screened at the University of Chicago's Doc Films last summer.
The film was probably Japanese. If I'm not mistaken, there was some sort of Wikipedia page, since I remember reading about the synopsis. There is something about three (?) men on some sort of island setting, and there being a couple who lives on the island. One of the men apparently starts an affair with the wife of the couple.

I found a possible match. 
In the Summer 2014 Doc Press Release PDF by University of Chicago's Doc Films, a movie was mentioned which could be a possible match: 

As mentioned by the wikipedia page here, it is a japanese movie, and:

Twelve men of a shipwreck find themselves on a desert island, which is only inhabited by a farmer and a beautiful woman.

and later, check what happens:

soon, discipline and rationality are replaced by a struggle for power and the woman.

The movie is in black-and-white and very low quality, check here a sample:



